# Power USB hub and Raspberry Pi with the same PSU

Tags: power-supply, electronics

I am still searching for a solution to conveniently power some external hard drivers.

I would like to use only one AC plug as I think it is not very efficient to use two different PSUs.

My idea is to split the cable from a 2.6A power supply. (actually I did not find a 2.7A one)

```
AC mains -> 5V 2,6A PSU --> USB micro plug -> Raspberry Pi (Model B)
                         \                         | USB data
                          \--> round DC plug -> powered USB Hub
```

So this is more an electrical engineering question: Is it okay to connect the 2.6A input to raspberry Pi and to the USB hub parallely?  Could there any overloading happen?

Answer (score 4):

Your config is good but i think is easier to make a ring!

```
RasPi USB --> Hub-USB --> RasPi MicroUsb power
```

Both solutions have the problem of [groundloop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_%28electricity%29)

You can avoid it by stripping the ground in the last connection:

```
Hub-USB --> RasPi MicroUsb power
```

or in your connection schema:

```
RasPi USB --> Hub-USB
```

2A power adapter is enough: i tested it with 2 USB self powered hdd, a wifi adapter and a usb lan adapter

**NOTE that this works only with version B**

Comment: But the USB hub would supply max 500mA per port - RasPi needs 700mA - how does that work?

Comment: @Alex hubs usb are dumber than you think. anyway as I said I tested this configuration. I also measured raspi B current for a day and it need 450mA if you use a powered hud with all usb device attached. I think they write 700 including usb devices

Comment: @Alex: 500mA should actually be enough for RasPi itself since all the other devices are powered by active hub. I also use the same setup and it works fine. All you have to remember is that you now can't disconnect microUSB cable to turn RasPi off, you have to disconnect the HUB.

Comment: @giammin: What do you mean by striping the ground?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski it is better to avoid groundloop. it is enought to remove the ground from the cable that power raspi from hubusb. in this way the usb ground is not looped

Comment: @giammin: It seems that my knowledge of electronics is to small so I don't understand it. Ground from RasPi is already connected to the HUB ground by RasPi USB -> Hub-USB cable. What will it change if we remove ground cable from RasPi power input? Isn't it all connected already?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski you avoid a groundloop: raspiusb---hub---raspipower---ruspiusb. a goundloop act as an antenna for electrostatic charge and can lead to interference or in worst cases to electric shok (mainly during storm)

Comment: @giammin: Actually I mis-read your answer first. I actually understood that I get a ground loop in my setup. But this is about your setup :-) Would my setup cause any problems then? Advantage would be also that I have one additional free hub port.

Comment: @Alex You have indeed a groundloop too in your configuration! anyway your configuration is good. I think mine is simpler to achieve. Yours saves only a usb port

Comment: @giammin: But for your's I also have to cut a wire in the USB cable, right? How can I avoid my groundloop?

Comment: @Alex you can also open the hub usb and cut the ground connection in one join.

Comment: @giammin: still involves messing around with the hardware --- do you have an advice how I can remove the ground loop from my solution?

Comment: @Alex you can also live with it. maybe it will never give you a problems. it is not automatically. it is just a best practice to avoid ground loop. the easier way I can think is to remove the external shield of an usb connector (like in some pendrive: http://www.levelpc.es/1365-4047-thickbox/corsair-voyager-mini-usb-pendrive-4gb.jpg )

Comment: @giammin: I would like to do it is properly as possible. From which plug do I have to remove the shield in my setup? Maybe you can post this also as additional answer to avoid flooding the comments here ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about a ground loop in the power circuit. Typically you'd be lucky to see 0.1V along the loop unless you have _huge_ alternating magnetic fields nearby. Ground loops in audio circuits are another matter.

Answer (score 3):

I found a USB hub: "Plugable USB 2.0 4 Port Hub / BC1.1 Charging.  It came with 2.5A @ 5V power supply. The BC means Battery Charger - has the power to charge an IPAD via USB without being connected to computer. Also has the needed up-link cable (2ft USB A to USB mini A)

I got USB A to USB Micro-B 6" cable to power RPi.  Then hooked the RPi to the up-link port.  With the setup, I power the PI and still have 3 ports open, That have Wireless NIC and 16GB Memory stick and a port left over for a disk drive from time to time.  Since my unit is model B, the second USB port has a wireless keyboard/mouse.

Does look a little funny with USB cables entering both ends of RPi, but work very nicely.